# How does "only:" at "before_action" work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After scaffold generation we usually get a line like that:

```ruby
before_action :set_newsletter_email, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Could someone explain to me how exactly this `only:` symbol works?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `only` option of `before_action` defines one action OR a list of actions when the method/block will be executed first.

Ex:

```
# defined actions: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_newsletter_email, only: [:show, :edit]
```

The `set_newsletter_email` method will be called just before the `show` and `edit` actions.

---

The opposite option `except` define when NOT to execute the method/block.

```
# defined actions: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_newsletter_email, except: [:show, :edit]
```

The `set_newsletter_email` method will be called for all existing actions EXCEPT `show` and `edit`.

---

`only` / `except` is just a kind of whitelist/blacklist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your example was firstly not fully clear for me because of list of available actions in comment - you meant that available actions are just all actions defined in the controller, didn't you?

Comment: @KarolSelak yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Option `:only` runs a method, ':set_newsletter_email' in this example, when any of the action defined in the list in square brackets `[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` is called in the current controller and runs before the actions is run. Any other action defined in the controller will not execute `:set_newsletter_email` method.

You can also do the opposite with `:except` option to define method that will run on every actions defined in the controller except the one's that are listed.

You can also do `after_action` that will run after the action in the controller

You can read about the filters and all the options here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Answer (score 1):

When a user navigates only to those routes, it will trigger the `:set_newsletter_email` function, usually at the end of that controller file.

So when the user navigates to the index method, it will not trigger it because `:set_newsletter_email` is **only** called for the methods on brackets.

In this case that callback is needed because it sets the resource in the single resource views before it is rendered.

For example:

`/newsletter/2` route will trigger the `:set_newsletter_email` that will first get the id from the link params and then it will look for the resource and set an instance variable with it.

I don't know what is your concern about security in this case, but this callback only gets the id param to set the resource and because you're using scaffolds it also generates a params function (also at the end of the file) that whitelists the parameters you defined earlier while generating the scaffold.

You can find more info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html

If you want me to explain more or clarify something just ask